# React application on chrome os

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-os

I have such problem. I had order on React Native App for Android. After provide prototype client told me that he want it on device (huge tablet) with chrome os. Google answered me that impossible is run on this device Android native apps.

My question is: Does it possible to make in ReactJS/React native webapp for Chrome OS what use device camera and use it for barcode scan? The best by ready barcode scanner component.

I found react-native-for-web but I'm not sure how I should use it. Will appreciate for any hints. Unfortunately information what I found so far are not clear for me.
Also helpful would be information, how I can run any emulator on macOS because this device is far away from me.

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: I´m starting researching this. Have you found anything meanwhile?